# Regular Expressions with Regex

Tags: c#, java

we need to find if the expression is correct or not using regex, it also includes checking the format of "if statements" 
eg: case1:

```
 if(x==1)
   x = x+1;
```

would say correct.
 case2:

```
else x=x+1;
```

would say false as 'if part' is missing

Comment: Are you talking about lexical parsing of source code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can't parse code with regular expressions.

Think of the following, you have a simple mathematical expression:

```
((x+y))+z...
```

With arbitrarily many parenthesis, how would you match it with a regular expression? You need some form of *memory* which regular languages do not have.

You can't. More formally, it can be shown (with the pidgeon-hole principle) that the language `A*B*` (where * is the [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star)) is not regular. (More than that, common dialects of regex can't parse it)

Comment: thank you :) 
it was our assignment but i believe it is not possible to achieve this task with Regex, have to do with some other way...

Comment: You need some sort of lexer/tokenizer , you can _use_ regex in your tokenization, but you can't feed a program into a regex and have it spit 'valid' or 'invalid'.

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't the right tool for this.  You'll want something a lot closer to a parser generator.

Comment: yeah will be doing the parsing of expressions!

Comment: As the other responses have said, you're looking at something like
statement := if (booleanExpr) statement else statement.  This can nest indefinitely and requires *at least* a pushdown automata and can't be described using a regex.